# When compilerOptions.strict is true in tsconfig.json, nested *ngIf="false" creates "Error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'"

Tags: angular, typescript

I can not figure out why a simple `*ngIf="false"` will cause `error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.`.

---

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strict": true,
```

---

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  user? : User;
}

interface User {
  name: string;
}
```

---

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <div>{{user.name}}</div> <!-- OK -->
  <div *ngIf="true">{{user.name}}</div>  <!-- OK -->
  <div *ngIf="false">{{user.name}}</div>  <!-- error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'. -->
</div>
```

---

Full Angular project: https://gitlab.com/zchlian/angular-test-strict/